# Ember Custom Serializer not being called for the main route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My custom serializer works fine for routes like `posts/1`, `posts/2`, etc. But it is never called for `posts/`.

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  init() {
    console.log('init'); // never called for the main route

    this._super();
  }
});
```

Comment: Which routes do you mean? Ember routes?

Comment: Serializers are not called for routes; they're called for models. By the way, what is the name of this serializer file?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes I know that. There is a model `Post` and it works fine with data from `Mirage`. I want to switch to some custom API, in order to do this I need to write custom serializer. And it works for single post `posts/:post_id` however it is not called when I want to list all posts `/posts`. Serializer name is `posts.js`. I've tried `application.js` as well.

Comment: @locks for the `/posts` URL - to list all posts, works for single post however